# PCSXR Emulator switching sound profiles in pulse audio

Tags: sound, games, emulation

First of all I'm running lubuntu 16.04, it wont be upgrading anytime soon due to kernel stability for this specific device.

So heres what's happening, when I launch a game on PCSXR the profile in pulse audio is switching to the laptop speakers when it should be staying on the HDMI profile on the TV for audio.

I can't test anything out until Saturday this week and I am pulling my hair out researching a fix for this issue, is there a way that I can stop this from happening?

Comment: On April 30 you can sign up for the free ESM and continue to receive security patches for 16.04

Comment: Meanwhile check PCSXR settings. It may have a default of fallback audio output setting somewhere.

Comment: I could try a different spu, I will find out once I get to my girlfriends place tomorrow and check some settings with the default.pa file. Worst case I could always go with mednafen which already runs doom specifically for the frontend on retroarch. Sometimes emulation accuracy is better than better visuals anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some mucking around I got something that's working.

I've got some modified scripts and cores with retroarch that launches the script directly on my girlfriend's media computer I maintain for her, here's what I did.

In the i3 configuration file I set the profile in pulseaudio to default to her specified preferred audio output

```
exec pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3 output:hdmi-stereo
```

I then added these launching in a bash script on psx launch to default back to her pulseaudio profile that gets launched by retro arch.

```
#!/bin/bash
antimicro --hidden --profile /home/USER/.config/antimicro/gaming.gamecontroller.amgp &
/home/USER/.config/retroarch/roms/audioworkaround.sh &
pcsx -nogui -cdfile "/home/USER/Documents/Emulation/Playstation/Crash Bandicoot 3/Crash Bandicoot - Warped (USA).bin"
/home/USER/.config/retroarch/roms/audioworkaround.sh &
antimicro --hidden --profile /home/USER/.config/antimicro/home.gamecontroller.amgp
```

It will go to my my audio work around script that sleeps for 6 seconds and switch to the profile on what I did in my i3 configuration file, thanks for some of the advice guys